# Play video from YouTube direct on website with HTML

Tags: html, css

I wrote some HTML code to play video direct from YouTube. My code is like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-6">
  <h2 class="line-bottom mt-0">University <span class="text-theme-colored2">Video</span></h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="box-hover-effect play-button">
        <div class="effect-wrapper">
          <div class="thumb">
            <img class="img-fullwidth" src="images/about/5.jpg" alt="project">
          </div>
          <div class="overlay-shade bg-theme-colored"></div>
          <div class="video-button"></div>
          <a class="hover-link" data-lightbox-gallery="youtube-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om4qTKMuPPs" title="Youtube Video">Youtube Video</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, after clicking the play button, nothing is happening. Is there anything wrong in my code? How will I play the video?

Answer (score 1):

To show the video on your website (at the moment you're only linking to it), use an iframe to embed the video. Your iframe src will be made up of your youtube url with the `watch?v=` part replaced by `embed/`.  E.g.:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/om4qTKMuPPs" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Alternately, if you want to retain the link, you could type e.g. 'video' and insert a hyperlink to the youtube embed url. [See video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/om4qTKMuPPs)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to embed video from YouTube "normal" video URL won't work properly. You need "embed video URL" and can found that way:

1. Under video on YouTube click button "Share...".
2. Click first circle with name "Embed".
3. Now you can configure embedded video and copy whole `<iframe>` or as you need copy just right URL address to this shared video.

In your case the URL is https://www.youtube.com/embed/om4qTKMuPPs, so replace with it your `a href=""` ;)

---

[Here is working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tester500/r9txedvf/) with Your code with my solution used.

Comment: I edited answer and add working fiddle with my solution.

Comment: Let us know if solution worked for You by accepting answer ;) If not I will try to help u solve the issue.

Comment: Add code directly into the answer; don't use external sites to store code snippets